# Accuracy of Google Analytics results - visits/visitors with GA iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics, ios5, web-analytics

I have encountered missleading numbers in GA reports.
I've made an experiment - during single app session (about 30 mins) I've logged about 100 tracks (pageviews and events) from my iPhone. One strange thing is that after this session I have 11 visits - few from iPhone and few not set and 6 unique visitors. I was logging that tracks using three networks, only initial was logged.

Here is a link to discussion on GA forum http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=2779ad95e20f32bd&hl=en

Have you encountered same problems guys? Is there a cure for this?